# list all user's objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, show

as the title says I'm trying to list all cars of one specific user, also each car has two options show and update [image]

as you see in the picture, my problem is when I want to show or edit the selected car, it routes (look the bottom left of the image) it takes all the ids of all the cars for example users/"id"/cars/"id1"/"id2" instead to take the id of the specific car: users/"id"/cars/"id1"/
here is te index.html.erb file:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Listing Cars</h1>

<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @car.each do |car| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= car.brand %></td>
      <td><%= car.color %></td>
      <td><%= car.model %></td>
      <td><%= car.year %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_car_path(@user,@car) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_car_path(@user, @car) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
<br />
<%= link_to 'New car', new_user_car_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

and whether you need the car controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.cars.build
end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.cars.build(params[:car])
      if @car.save
        redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car), :flash => { :notice => "  car created!" }
      else
        redirect_to new_user_car_path ,:flash => { :notice => " sorry try again :(" }
      end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])     
  @car = @user.cars.find(params[:id]) 
  #redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)  
end
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])     
  @car = @user.cars.all
end
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])     
  @car = @user.cars.find(params[:id]) 
  #redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)  
end
def update
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])  
@car = @user.cars.find(params[:id])
if @car.update_attributes(params[:car])
  redirect_to user_cars_path, :flash => { :notice => "  Car Updated!" }
else
  render 'edit'
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a Ruby enumerator, the block variable is each member of the enumerator, one after the other. So if, in your sample code, `@cars` is `["Toyota", "Mazda", "Honda"]`, then `car` will be first `"Toyota"`, then `"Mazda"`, then `"Honda"`.

This is a long way of saying you're using the instance variable when you should be using the block variable. ;) Correct your code to look like this:

```
  <% @car.each do |car| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= car.brand %></td>
      <td><%= car.color %></td>
      <td><%= car.model %></td>
      <td><%= car.year %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_car_path(@user, car) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_car_path(@user, car) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

It should be `car`, not `@car`, in your routes.